# How to count mean on two dim array in numpy by axis including only specific values?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. The first one is an array with values and the second one contains zeros and ones. They have the same shape. I want to count mean for every row of the first array but including only values on index where is 1 in the second array. Let's say it's `A=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).reshape(3,3)` and `B=np.array([1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]).reshape(3,3)`. And finally I want to have an array like this `array([1.5,5,7])`.

I was trying to do it with np.putmask, but I don't have any proper values to put in there.
Also, no loops are out of the question. I need maximum performance with this.

Comment: `(A*B).sum(1) / B.sum(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can mask with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and use [`nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
out = np.nanmean(np.where(B, A, np.nan), axis=1)
```

output: `array([1.5, 5. , 7. ])`

Intermediate:

```
np.where(B, A, np.nan)

array([[ 1.,  2., nan],
       [ 4., nan,  6.],
       [ 7., nan, nan]])
```